Eslint configuration for padding-line-between-statements
We are trying to achieve a different linting behavior when a const declaration is inside a function and when it is not. In top level scope, we want one line between them. Inside blocks (if statements, functions, classes, etc) no line between.
Desired:
const foo = 'foo';

const bar = 'bar';

const baz = ()=> {
 const hello = 'hello';
 const wolrd = 'world';
}


Incorrect:
//Incorrect, top level should have a space between consts
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';

const baz = ()=> {
 //incorrect, block scoped should be continuos.
 const hello = 'hello';

 const wolrd = 'world'
}


I have tried to add to my .eslintrc file:
"padding-line-between-statements": [
  "error",
  { "blankLine": "never", "prev": "const", "next": "const"},
],

But this will force always to remove the line.
Same behaviour but opposite for:
{ "blankLine": "always", "prev": "const", "next": "const"},

But always succeeded in providing the same behavior in the 2 situations I explained.
I am not nailing how to differentiate among them in the settings
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

First, according to https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files, eslintrc is deprecated. You should use the latest eslint.config.js/eslint.config.mjs/eslint.config.cjs for your configuration.
With that said, have you tried adding the "group" property?
{
  "rules":{
    "prefer-const": ["error", { "destructuring": "any", "ignoreReadBeforeAssign": false }],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "const", "next": "const", "group": "top-level" },
      { "blankLine": "never", "prev": "const", "next": "const", "group": "block-like" }
    ]
  }
}


Thanks for the reply. Neverless the file name, which as you said, it should be updated, it falls out of scope for the question.
Regarding your suggestion, the group property fails:
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.57.0

Error: .eslintrc.json:
 Configuration for rule "padding-line-between-statements" is invalid:
 Value {"blankLine":"always","prev":"const","next":"const","group":"top-level"} should NOT have additional properties.

I also couldn't find that option documented in the docs, can you point me to some docs on that if you used successfully? thanks.

Same here. This property is not allowed there.
